# Expected size of $k$-th layer of a POSET

Tags: pr.probability, order-theory

Is this known?

What is the expected width of the $k$-th layer (anti-chain layer) of a $d$-dimensional partially ordered set of $n$ elements formed by product of $d$ random linear orders chosen from the same distribution.

It is well known for $k = 1$ (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00582738). But not able to find any reference for $k > 1$.